# what is the meaning of the phrase "broken in"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, vocabulary

I have read this phrase

> There were all these mutant skeletons in there, of Muggles who'd
> *broken in* and grown extra heads and stuff

(From *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*. page 1)

and can not understand the phrase "*broken in*". Can anyone help me?

Comment: Arman.  Where did you read this.  I'm pretty sure it is from Harry Potter, but which book?  Which page?

Comment: Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban. page 1

Answer (score 1):

To "break in" means to force your way into a place, typically to steal. "Broken in" is a past participle of this.

Comment: It's actually a past participle, not past tense. In any case, it is OP's responsibility to look up basic definitions.

Comment: thanks for answer

Comment: This is already provided in an existing answer.

Comment: You mean the answer that was given 6 hours after this one, @Joachim?

Comment: @ColinFine I do, my apologies, but this was in the first answers queue (I believe), hence the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of "**break in**" according to the [Cambridge Dictionary.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/)

> An occasion when a building is entered illegally by a criminal or
> criminals, usually by damaging a window or door, especially in order
> to steal something

And "**broken**" is the past participle of "**break**".

| Present Simple | Past Simple | Past Participle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| break | broke | broken |